# Factor Analysis in Deep Learning

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

I'm new to deep learning and currently trying to use it for my project. The goal is to predict ship charter prices based on various factors that we have identified theoretically. In this project, we also want to understand how these factors affect ship charter prices and specifically determine the extent of their influence.

We already have data on ship charter prices and the related factors. However, I have searched and couldn't find a way in Python's deep learning to determine which factors have the most significant impact on the model (if you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate them).

So, my idea is to perform factor analysis, particularly exploratory factor analysis (EFA) and confirmatory factor analysis (CFA), to understand the structural relationships between the factors. However, I'm unsure if factor analysis is necessary in this case. While factor analysis provides correlations and identifies underlying or latent variables in the factor structure, it doesn't directly show how these factors influence the dependent variable (ship charter prices).

Should I use factor analysis in this case, or am I not aware if factor analysis can provide the insights I'm looking for?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is probably helpful if you report the number of predictors and the number of observations of you dataset, and whether and why you _have_ to use deep learning. My first impression is that deep learning may not be needed. If you want interpretability, a regularized regression model might suit your needs. One can also perform CFA and include ship charter prices as a response variable, predicted by the latent variable(s). In terms of predictive accuracy, the latter approach will likely only do well if you have solid prior knowledge about the dependence structure of the various factors.

Comment: currently, im having 23 of total predictors and around 5000 observation. sadly i dont have prior knowledge about this industry or any latent factors that maybe affecting the rate.